# GCC option : Unrecognized command line

Tags: compile, make, gcc, arm, makefile

I am trying to build my project with the gcc compiler, but I get this error:

> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mthumb'

Isn't `-mthumb` a default option for gcc?

---

output of `gcc --version`:

> gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.8.4 20140526 (release)
>       [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 211358]

`make` version is 3.81

I am building with `make` version 3.81 for the Cortex-M4 architecture.

Comment: Just to add `-mthumb` is documented for GCC 4.4 and 8.2.  Perhaps posting the command line would have helped, in case the options has become entwined in some other context?

Comment: ahh, so you say it was probably because of a too old `make` in his case, @simon.watts? I got the same error when trying to compile an ARM project on an x86 GCC, as this is an ARM specific option.

Comment: @hoijui I don't think this is a `make` issue -- that would often exhibit as empty variables (expansions from missing make functions - run with  `--warn-undefined-variables`).  I was just checking when the `-mthumb` option was added to GCC, and it certainly predates 4.8.4.  I would question whether there is something different in the ARM branch compared to baseline, or whether its possible the option appeared on the command line where something else was expected (such as a parameter to a preceding option, or similar).